# CSS minmax invalid property value

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I want to set the `minmax` property for my `grid-template-columns`. But for some reason I don't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
.start {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(320px, 1fr) minmax(320px, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 2%;
}

<div class="start">
  <div class="news"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the `.start` class in Chrome, it just says "invalid property value" for the `minmax` attribute.

I just want a two-column layout which becomes a one-column layout when the viewport gets to narrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(320px, 1fr));
```

For smaller screens, where you want one column, use a media query to run this:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
```

---

The proper syntax for `minmax()` is detailed in the chart below ([taken from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)).

Notice that there is no option for `minmax()` followed by another `minmax()` in the track lists. That's why your rule is invalid.

[image]

Here's the complete explanation:

- [7.2. Explicit Track Sizing: the `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)

Answer (score -1):

The minmax() CSS function defines a size range greater than or equal to min and less than or equal to max.

```
/* <inflexible-breadth>, <track-breadth> values */
minmax(200px, 1fr)
minmax(400px, 50%)
minmax(30%, 300px)
minmax(100px, max-content)
minmax(min-content, 400px)
minmax(max-content, auto)
minmax(auto, 300px)
minmax(min-content, auto)

/* <fixed-breadth>, <track-breadth> values */
minmax(200px, 1fr)
minmax(30%, 300px)
minmax(400px, 50%)
minmax(50%, min-content)
minmax(300px, max-content)
minmax(200px, auto)

/* <inflexible-breadth>, <fixed-breadth> values */
minmax(400px, 50%)
minmax(30%, 300px)
minmax(min-content, 200px)
minmax(max-content, 200px)
minmax(auto, 300px)
```